# How to access style with $refs?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I used `console.log(this.$refs['block' + row + column]);` to make sure that I can access the HTML element it refers to, and I can get that HTML element successfully.

[image: console output]

But I tried to access that element's style by multiple ways I found online, it always says undefined:

1. `this.$refs['block' + row + column].style.backgroundColor = this.colors[toColor];`

[image]

2. `this.$refs['block' + row + column].$el.style.backgroundColor = this.colors[toColor];`

[image]

I wonder what is causing this error? Is that I'm not accessing the style correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The result is an array, so you can use `this.$refs['block' + row + column][0].style.backgroundColor = this.colors[toColor];` to set the data. I hope it does work for you.